# Memoizing arguments independently

Tags: haskell, memoization

I have a simulation with lots of calls to functions of the `type F = A -> B -> C -> D`, where `A`..`D` are concrete types.

The objects of type `A` have a medium lifetime. (It is the genome of [codegolf's ratrace](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/44707/lab-rat-race-an-exercise-in-genetic-algorithms).)

The most expensive computation arises from parameter `A`. I can easily memoize like this:

```
f1 :: F
f1 a = let expensive = trace "expensive computation!" $ expensiveComputation a
        in \b c -> expensive
```

and hold some pre-processed `expensive` values via partial application:

```
preProz :: [B -> C -> D]
preProz = [f1 [], f1 [False], f2 []]
```

The traces indicate that `preProz <*> [[],[[]]] <*> [1,2]` does not recompute the values to my delight.

Now I found out that some of my `F`s would benefit from pre-processing `B`, too. This pre-processing is *independent* from `A`, and, in fact, memoizing like this has no benefit

```
f2 a = let expensive = trace "expensive computation!" $ expensiveComputation a
        in \b -> let dear = trace "expensive computation!" $ expensiveComputation b
                  in expensive + dear
```

because `dear` is recomputed, even is the `b`s equal.

What I need is something like:

```
(B -> e) -> A -> e -> C -> D
```

where `e` should be memoized. The type of `e` is sort-of-existential here.
But this forces me to recompute all values `A` for every `B`, which is just as bad, and I cannot save the `e`s, which are private to the function.

How can I memoize along 2 parameters independently?

Comment: Does pre-processing of A depend on B or vice versa? If pre-processing doesn't depend on other arguments, why not just move it of the function: `f1 <$> [procA a1, procA a2] <*> [procB b1, procB b2] <*> ...` Now preprocessing is guaranteed to run only once for each argument.

Comment: I mean "move it out of the function".

Comment: "does not recompute the values is[as?] intended" is an ambiguous phrasing: it could also mean "I expected it to recompute, and it did not"

Answer (score 1):

You need a function that memoizes both `a` and `b` together:

```
f12 a b = ...
    in \c -> ...
```

When you want to memoize `a` but not `b`, you use `f1 a` and when you want to memoize both you use `f12 a b`.

It would of course be nice to share some implementation between `f1` and `f12`. However, you can do that only by having private functions that take the precomputed results in place of the original values:

```
f1 a = privateA (precomputeA a)
f12 a b = privateAB (precomputeA a) (precomputeB b)
privateA a' b = privateAB a' (precomputeB b)
private AB a' b' c = ...
```

If the precomputation of `b` depends on the precomputation of `a`, then:

```
f1 a = privateA (precomputeA a)
f12 a b = let a' = precomputeA a in privateAB a' (precomputeB a' b)
privateA a' b = privateAB a' (precomputeB a' b)
private AB a' b' c = ...
```

I've purposely not used function composition and eta-reduction, to make things clearer. I've also left out any strictness annotations that you might want to use to control times of evaluation.

Perhaps memoizing isn't quite the right term here. You mean something like "partial application with some precomputation as well."